# Use a CX_Oracle SQL output to Trigger a Python Script

Tags: sql, python-2.7, cx-oracle

I looking for a bit of help in producing a SQL table update checker. For example I have a SQL table on a oracle Database classing each day as a colour (Single value).

```
 DATE     |   Colour
 25/08/16 |   Blue
 24/08/16 |   Red
 23/08/16 |   Red
 22/08/16 |   Blue
```

I'm using CX_Oracle to connect with the database, but I need an output back that says whether it's a Red day or Blue day. Then I want to combine this value with an if statement that says if today = blue then run Blue.PY script else if Red run Red.PY else if null then wait 60 mins & check again.

I'm stuck on how to pull the output from CX_Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is short on details on how a day is considered red or blue...but the basic idea would be as follows:

```
import cx_Oracle

conn = cx_Oracle.Connection("user/pw@tns")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select TheDate from TheTable")
for theDate, in cursor:
    if theDate.day in (22, 25):
        run_script("Blue.py")
    else:
        run_script("Red.py")
```

The method run_script() would do whatever you needed to do to run the red or blue scripts. And the if clause would need to be adjusted to handle whatever actually makes a date red or blue.